# SVN Error (Can't set file)

Tags: tortoisesvn

Everytime I try to commit files to SVN I got the following error.

```
Command            Commit
Modified           D:\Project\src\WebSite\SomePage.aspx.cs
Sending Content    D:\Project\AKent\src\WebSite\Test\SomePage.aspx.cs
Commit succeeded, but other errors follow:
Error bumping revisions post-commit (details follow):
Can't set file 'D:\Project\AKent\src\WebSite\Test\SomePage.aspx.cs'
 read-write: Access is denied.
```

After I get this error, SVN doesnt allow me to update or commit anything! And what is really frustrating me is that the project folder is around 2 GB and every night I download it from SVN over and over.

Please help me to fix it! I just wanna know what is wrong with my SVN. I tried reinstalling, didn't fix anything.

Comment: Did you do a clean-up on the whole directory structure?  Have you had a look at the ACLs on BelgeGoruntule.aspx.cs -- do they look different?

Comment: test your post-commit hook, as it noted in error-message

Comment: When I click on clean-up option, 6 different options show up and non of them seem to be working due to error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error

> read-write: Access is denied.

indicates that svn can not access the file or can't set all attributes it needs to that file.
Now that either means you have not full access to those files or some other application has the file opened exclusively.

In the first case: make sure that your username has full access to all folders and subfolders of your working copy. Note that on Vista/Win7 it's not enough to be an admin - you have to give yourself full access to such files manually.k

In the second case: disable windows search indexer for your working copy, and exclude the working copy from being scanned by your virus scanner.

Comment: I did all this; did not help. I suggest the second answer below by @Soony is more definitive.

Answer (score 36):

I had the same problem but fixed. My solution is:

```
1. Run Command Prompt as Administrator

2. Navigate to the target working copy 

3. svn cleanup
```

Comment: Worked for me as well; no amount of changes via TortoiseSVN was giving any relief.

Comment: worked for me as well.  Had to go back to my tortoise SVN install and add the command line tools since it wasn't there already.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sharing a svn versioned folder using samba and running into this issue when acessing it from windows machine, try:

http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#samba

Also add to your smb.conf file:

```
dos filemode = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

1. copy the wrong folder (1) to another folder(2)
2. delete the wrong folder (1)
3. copy the backup(2) to (1)
   Hope this approach works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to revert a file but was receiving the error listed in the OP's post.  Soony's answer just about worked for me.  I cannot comment or edit that answer, so I had to copy their answer and add a small step at the end.  S/he deserves all the credit.

1. Run Command Prompt as Administrator
2. Navigate to the target working
3. copy  svn cleanup
4. **svn revert [filename]**

(the revert did not work in Windows Explorer/TortoiseSVN integrated tools, I had to do it from the cmd line)